# Why can't I convert DynamicJson to my class if I don't write {get; set;}

Tags: c#, json

I have a very simple class

```
public class A
{
    public List<int> intList_a = new List<int>(); // {get; set;}
}
```

and I have

```
        A a = DynamicJson.Parse("{\"intList_a\":[0, 1]}");
        A a2 = DynamicJson.Parse("{\"a\":{}}");
        Console.WriteLine(a.intList_a.First());
        Console.WriteLine(a2.intList_a.Count);
```

I find that if I write {get; set;} instead of new List(); I can convert the values in json to a.intList_a. Otherwise I [0,1] won't go into my List.

However, sometimes I need to find out a2.intList_a.Count. If I just use {get; set;}, intList will be null. I know I can check null everytime I call Count. But it will be easier if I can new it at init since most of the time I need the value.

I also understand that I C#6.0 makes it easier but my working environment does not allow me upgrade.

So why I must write {get; set;} to make [0, 1] into the list?
Is there anyway to get both features that I can get my List a default new List() while I can Parse them into my A?

I can write new in constructors but my data class is too huge to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a field and a property in C#.

```
Int32 thisIsAField = 0;
Int32 ThisIsAProperty { get; set; }
```

Dynamic object can have additional properties that are created/discovered at runtime but not fields. `DynamicJson` uses internally the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) capabilities of C#.

But you can mix the two easily:

```
private IList<Int32> _intList = new List<Int32>();
public IList<Int32> IntList
{
    get { return this.intList; }
    set { this.intList = value; }
}
```

I don't know if this will work with `DynamicJson` but it does with other serialization systems.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I wonder is there a shorter way to do this so that I can find/replace them for my huge classes..